# Execution failed for task ':spoon'. > org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/util/CommentRecorderParser

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, inria-spoon

I am new to Spoon. I just know that using Spoon we can analyze and transform source code. I want to use Spoon in my gradle project. I am using IntelliJ IDEA for this project. I am getting this error when I tried to build the project.

Error:

```
Execution failed for task ':spoon'.
> org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/util/CommentRecorderParser
```

My `build.gradle` file is as follows :

```
group 'com.X'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'fr.inria.gforge.spoon:spoon-core:5.8.0'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'fr.inria.gforge.spoon',
                name: 'spoon-gradle-plugin',
                version:'1.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spoon'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'Main'
        )
    }
}
```

I got this when built with `--stacktrace`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/util/CommentRecorderParser
```

Please help me fix this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens with spoon because it's failing to find `org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/util/CommentRecorderParser` class in the classpath. Adding the following to your buildscript dependencies should do the trick:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath group: 'fr.inria.gforge.spoon',
            name: 'spoon-gradle-plugin',
            version:'1.1'
    classpath group: 'org.eclipse.jdt', name: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core', version: '3.12.2'
}
```

}